# Seeking a Function With Certain Properties

Tags: real-analysis

Let $|| \cdot ||$ denote the [Euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance). I am seeking a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ with the property that (i) all partial derivatives (of all orders) of $f$ vanish nowhere (i.e., all PDs are non-zero everywhere), (ii) $f$ is infinitely many times (Freceht) differentiable, and (iii)
$$
     \frac{|f(x)|}{||x||} \to M \hspace{6mm}\text{as}\hspace{6mm} ||x||\to\infty
$$
for some $M\in\mathbb{R}$ (originally, the question was $M=1$).
Any thoughts? Thanks for your time.

Edit 1: Clarifying that we desire that partial derivatives of every order exist.

Edit 2: Maybe this is easier, can we achieve $f(x) = \mathcal{O}(||x||)$ as $||x||\to\infty$??

Edit 3: Slightly easier still, if I change $f(x)/||x||$ to $|f(x)|/||x||$, can we achieve this??

Edit 4: Minute typo.

Edit 5: Slight change to choice of words to improve clarity.

Comment: Have you tried looking at f(x) = |x|?

Comment: Touche, I forgot to mention the smoothness that I require. I sort of alluded to it by mentioning that partial derivatives don't vanish, but I forgot to specify that I want them to exist and of all orders.

Comment: Maybe we could try to look for a function that approaches |x| in its limits then, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Yes, sorry for the initial ambiguity

Comment: @schmidt73 not a bad idea, I just now entertained the idea of taking $f(x) = ||x||\hspace{0.5mm} ||x-(1,\ldots,1)||$, in which case, I think, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} f(x) = x_i \frac{||x-(1,\ldots,1)||}{||x||} + (x_i-1) \frac{||x||}{||x-(1,\ldots,1)||}$, which still vanishes.

Comment: You could maybe define the function outside of some neighbourhood of zero (which seems much easier), then try to patch it up?

Comment: I like the idea, although it does make it tricky to get the final result to be $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, though not impossible. Let me think about that

Comment: For $n = 1$, take $f(x) = x$. For $n > 1$, if $M > 0$, then $f(x)$ has constant sign for large $\lVert x\rVert$, and $\lvert f(x)\rvert \to \infty$, therefore $f$ has a global minimum or maximum, say at $x_0$, and all partial derivatives vanish at $x_0$. For $M = 0$ one can do it. Are you interested in the $M = 0$ case?

Comment: Your $n=1$ case doesn't work, because already $f'' = 0$. He was seeking for a function with non-zero PDs of all orders. Also, a function with $f(x) \to \infty$ for $x \to \infty$ doesn't necessarily have a global maximum.

Comment: Wanting all PDs of all orders to not vanish anywhere means that the function has to rise or fall throughout. But also wanting to have that $f(x)$ grows "as fast as" $\Vert x \Vert$ seems kind of impossible to me.

Comment: @Mathy I definitely agree. This made me think perhaps I should modify the goal so that $|f(x)|/||x|| = \mathcal{O}(||x||)$. This way, maybe a function can be found which rises or falls throughout, as you say, and although it does not grow as fast as $||x||$, its *absolute value* grows as fast as $||x||$...... Now what would such a function be?

Comment: I'm imagining something like a sigmoid function rotated in some way to sweep out a proper hypersurface, but I don't know how to articulate this mathematically....

Comment: I'm starting to thing that a function with the desired properties could be $$ f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \hspace{2mm}=\hspace{2mm} \left( \prod_{i=1}^n \ln\left( 1 + e^{x_i} \right) \right)^p $$ for $0<p<0.5$, in which case we would get convergence to $M=0$ as $||x||\to\infty$, I think. I graphed this in the $n=2$ case with $p=0.4$ and it looks promising. **Can anyone see an issue with that**?

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm not *disinterested* in the $M=0$ case, although $M=1$ might be cooler!

Comment: Is @Mathy correct that you want all derivatives of every order to vanish nowhere? I thought "all partial derivatives" meant the first-order partial derivatives.

Comment: Yes, as Mathy interpreted the question. That's a fair point, though; I'll edit the question to try to make the intent unambiguous.